# Can I run MongoDB config servers on replica and shard server?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I need to setup a 3x3 MongoDB 3.2 Cluster (3 Shards, 6 Replicas) and would like to keep the number of servers as small as possible. Can I run the config servers on the replica and shard servers (I thought about running 9 config server (1 config shard and 8 replica shard))? And is it a good idea or are there problems when one or the other server goes down?

SO Questions [MongoDB shards and config servers on the same server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31130421/mongodb-shards-and-config-servers-on-the-same-server) and [Should I run MongoDB config and mongos on the same servers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20736801/should-i-run-mongodb-config-and-mongos-on-the-same-servers) mention that running config server on shards is not a good idea but is this still true for replicas even when using 9 config server?

Comment: what decision did you come to on this? currently debating double purposing shard servers as also replica servers for other shards.

Answer (score 1):

you can run config server & mongos on the same server.I don't think so 9 config server required according to me 3 config server enough.